# Getters en vuex devuelve una funcion en lugar del valor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, get, vuex

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que ya ha comenzado y mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una mutación, que generará un menú, dependiendo de si el usuario tiene permiso para acceder o no, esto se calcula con un getter.

```
let menuList = [];
appRouters.forEach(item => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  if (item.permission !== undefined) {
    let hasPermissionMenuArr = [];
    hasPermissionMenuArr = item.children.filter(child => {
      if (child.permission !== undefined) {
        //if (child.permission.includes('operator')) {
        console.log(hasPermission(child.permission))
          if (hasPermission(child.permission))  {
          return child;
        }
      } else {
        return child;
      }
    });
```

El código "funcionaría" bien, pero cuando accede a los captadores para comprobar si el usuario tiene permiso para ese menú, el captador devuelve la función que tiene para recibir los parámetros, y no el valor.

```
export const hasPermission = state => permission => {
return isGranted(state, permission);
};
```

aquí la otra función del getter

```
function isGranted(state, permissionName) {
  return (
    state.user !== undefined &&
    state.user.roles !== undefined &&
    state.user.roles.some(p => {
      return p.toLowerCase() === permissionName.toLowerCase();
    })
  );
}
```

Sé que el getter está llamando a una tercera función, pero incluso, al getter hasPermission solo le he puesto una devolución de un console.log del permiso que se le pasa, e incluso entonces devuelve la función en texto.

Se que hay algo que no entiendo

EDIT:
0

Si si lo probe ni bien me lo recomendaste, pero no funciono. Sinceramente no se que son captors. A lo que me refiero en el link que mande es lo sigueinte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi dice vuex qeu es la forma de hacerlo, en otra oportunidad en otro proyecto lo use asi y funcionaba, no entiendo porque no funciona ahora.

Perdon si no es que me cuesta, no quiero hacerles perder el tiempo pero necesitaba un poco de ayuda. De nuevo gracias por responder!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta.

Comment: Perdon me equivoque. Ahi va!

Answer (score 0):

Revisando, veo que tienes lo siguiente:

```
export const hasPermission = state => permission => {
    return isGranted(state, permission);
};
```

Si lo analizamos bien, es lógico que te retorne una funcion, debido a que estas creando a **hasPermission** como una funcion de flecha, que recibe un parámetro que llama **state**, pero **state** es otra funcion de flecha que recibe **permission**.

Entonces cuando haces lo siguiente:

```
console.log(hasPermission(state));
```

Lo que estas haciendo es que hasPermission se ejecute y retorne la funcion state pero no la ejecuta.

Te sugieron que modifiques el bloque inicial que tomé, donde crear la funcion de flecha de la siguiente manera:

```
export const hasPermission = (state, permission) => {
    return isGranted(state, permission);
};
```

De esta manera la funcion va a recibir un parametro, y va a ejecutar isGranted mandandole los parametros correspondientes.

Se ejecutaría de la siguiente manera:

```
console.log(hasPermission(state, permission));
```

Lo que no se es a que objeto haces referencia con el state, ya que en el código solo mandas 1 parámetro y la funcion **isGranted** requiere 2 parámetros.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder! Tu funcion seria la forma correcta y mas facil de hacerlo, el problema es que vuex, para recibir un parametro en un getters, el getters tiene que devolver una funcion, la cual es la que recibe el parametro. Lo que pasas ahi esta perfecto y funcionaria perfecto como una funcion java, pero no funciona en vuex.

 https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access
 
Soy nuevo en programacion en general, hace 2 meses que consegui mi nuevo trabajo asi que me cuesta.
 Gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: @Luka pero lo que compartes, en el enlace, con lo que tienes en el código arriba es muy diferente, porque tu realmente estás usando una funcion de flecha normal y no un captor. Los captores son los que tienen el comportamiento que me indicas. Intenta hacer lo qe te indico, si no te sirve podemos mirar como sería con la forma de los captores.

Comment: Ahi cree una respuesta para poder poner una imagen